# How to perform a complex range query in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, range

I have a table (Table A) with a field of integers (Field B). For each row of Table A, I would like to construct a range of +/- 100 surrounding the integer value of Field B then find all values from Field B that are within these ranges. The query needs to be performed for all values in Field B. The query needs to return each row that is within each row range. Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
Table A
_______
A    1000    
B    3000    
C    5000    
D    1090
```

Using the above Table A, the query would first find the ranges (+/- 100) for all integers in Field B.

```
900 - 1100
2900 - 3100
4900 - 5100
990 - 1190
```

The query would then iterate through these ranges and return rows from Table A that fall within the generated ranges. Using the above example, the query would return:

```
A    1000
A    1000
B    3000
C    5000
D    1090
D    1090
```

`A` and `D` are returned twice because it they fall within their own ranges. How can I construct a query that will return each row that falls between the range of each row? Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT t2.*
FROM tableA AS t1
INNER JOIN tableA AS t2 ON t2.fieldB >= (t1.fieldB - 100) AND t2.fieldB <= (t1.fieldB + 100)
```

Shouldn't A also be shown twice, since it's also in D's range? (that's the case with above query - if incorrect, please elaborate why ^^)

Comment: Then the above query will do exactly what you need :)

Answer (score 1):

Start with your inner-most pre-qualifier of every Table A record... Then re-join to table A again.  I've added the qualifying Group ranges low and hi to show the qualifier basis you were looking for...  In addition to D showing up twice, A should show up twice too as it qualifies the "D"s range too.

```
select 
      a2.ShowLetter,
      a2.FieldB,
      GrpRanges.RangeLow,
      GrpRanges.RangeHi
   from 
      ( select distinct 
              a1.FieldB - 100 as RangeLow,
              a1.FieldB + 100 as RangeHi
           from
              TableA a1 ) GrpRanges

      JOIN TableA a2
         on a2.FieldB between GrpRanges.RangeLow and GrpRanges.RangeHi
   order by 
      a2.ShowLetter
```